# How can I add a row in a table?

Tags: jquery

I have an aplication where the user enters in their question in the textarea and then clicks on the "Add Question" button to add the question in a new row. The problem is though that the application lets the user display one question in a new row, but when I want to submit a second question in a new row, it doesn't let me.

(In Jsfiddle it doesn't let you add the second question at all while in my application on the browser would not let you add the second question as well but it displays an alert stating question is not valid, this alert message should not appear unless question textarea is empty or contains less than 5 characters.)

So how come it does not let me add the second question in the table?

My code is in Jsfiddle, click [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B872J/1/)

JS ("nowrap - in body" option in jsfiddle):

```
function insertQuestion(form) {   

    alertErrors = "",
    // Note, this is just so it's declared...
    qnum = 1;

    if (form.questionText.value == ""){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
    } 
    else if (form.questionText.value.length < 5){
        alertErrors += "\nYou have not entered a valid Question\n";
    }

    // Stop execution with a return
    if (alertErrors != "") {
        alert(alertErrors);
        return;
    }

    var $tr = $("<tr></tr>");
    var $qid = $("<td class='qid'>" + qnum + "</td>");
    var $question = $("<td class='question'></td>");

    $('#questionTextArea').each( function() {

        var $this = $(this);
        var $questionText = $("<textarea></textarea>")
                       .attr('name',$this.attr('name'))
                       .attr('value',$this.attr('value'))

        $question.append($questionText);

    });

    $tr.append($qid);
    $tr.append($question);

    $('#qandatbl').append($tr);

    form.numberOfQuestions.value = qnum;

    ++qnum;
    $("#questionNum").text(qnum);
    form.questionText.value = "";
}
```

HTML:

```
<form id="enter" action="<?php echo htmlentities($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']); ?>" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm(this);" >
<div id="detailsBlock">
<table id="question">
<tr>
    <th colspan="2">
        Question Number <span id="questionNum">1</span>
    </th>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td rowspan="3">Question:</td> 
    <td rowspan="3">
        <textarea id="questionTextArea" rows="5" cols="40" name="questionText"></textarea>
    </td>
</tr>
</table>

    <table id="questionBtn" align="center">
<tr>
<th>
<input id="addQuestionBtn" name="addQuestion" type="button" value="Add Question" onClick="insertQuestion(this.form)" />
</th>
</tr>
</table>

</div>
<hr/>

<table id="qandatbl" border="1">
<tr>
    <th class="qid">Question No</th>
    <th class="question">Question</th>

</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Make sure to post your code in the question too, in case jsfiddle.net goes down, and so that people can find your question when searching for related issues.

Comment: thanks merlyn morgan graham :)

Comment: Thanks everybody for your answers, much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inserting the first textarea you'll have 2 form-elements with the name "questionText".

form.questionText now will return a NodeList instead of an element, what results in an error, because a NodeList does not have a property "value".

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/B872J/8/

Answer (score 0):

I think I know what the issue is.  When you create your table rows, you add an input with the name value of "questionText" as the content of one of the cells.  Because your form encompasses the entire html, this results in duplicate questionText inputs.  When it then tries to check the value of questionText, it doesn't know which one to use.  According to the javascript console in chrome, it is at that point dealing with nodeList (EDIT: ... not array... nodelist... I should have know that) of input elements.  The simple solution is to change the location of the closing `</form>` tag to just before the `<hr>` tag.

[Forked Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wza6n/)

This will limit it to the original input element removing the possibility of running into duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

try like this using jquery. http://jquery-howto.blogspot.com/2009/02/add-table-row-using-jquery-and.html

Answer (score 0):

I made an update to your fiddle.. try it [here](http://jsfiddle.net/B872J/7/), The problem in your original fiddle was that it was sending nothing in the form.questionText in the second call

Comment: Hi, this works for the current example, but lets say I include another textarea for answer and want to add that in the table row with the question, will that work or not if I use your theory?

Comment: it should work just the same way I believe. You will just need to select the answer text using jQuery and pass it to your function